# D3.js just drawing a vertical line not actually graphing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I've been searching my thorugh a bunch of posts and tutorials trying to figure out d3, and I think I got most of it fingured out, but this is not drawing a line, and I don't know why. It's a simple `d3.line()` graph. The data had to be transformed into a format suitible for `.line()`, and it was. I also confirmed in console that that data was in the format

```
[{time: 1881, temp: -10} , {time: 1882, temp: -9 } ...]
```

If anyone could help me out with this I'd appreciate it. Also any good tutorials out ther efor d3 v4?

```
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var margin = 25;
    var axisLength = width - 2 * margin;


    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .style("border", "1px solid");



     // 5. X scale will use the index of our data
     var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent([new Date(1881,0,1),new Date(2015,0,1)]))
        .range([0, width]); // output

    // 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(tempArrMap["Glob"], function(d) {return d;})) 
        .range([height, 0]); // output 

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    svg.append("g")
          .classed("x-axis", true)
          .attr("transform", function() {
            return "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")";
          })
        .call(xAxis);




    var yrsCol = getCol(tempData,0)
    var globCol = getCol(tempData,1);


    var LineData = { x:yrsCol, y:globCol};

    function fn(data){
        var out = data.y.map(function (_, idx) {
           return { time: data.x[idx], temp: data.y[idx] }; 
    });
       return out;
    }

     svg.append("g")
         .classed("y-axis", true)
          .attr("transform", function() {
       return "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")";
      })
     .call(yAxis);

    var inLineData = fn(LineData);
```

`inLineData` now in a form suitable for `d3.line()` is an array of objects in form. I have confirm the data's validity thorough console.

`[{time: 1881, temp: -10} , {time: 1882, temp: -9 } ...]`

```
    var line = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.time); })
          .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.temp); });

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(inLineData))
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("transform", function() {
        return "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")";
      });
```

Comment: Your`time` properties are not dates, but simply numbers. You have to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, it appears you are missing your D3 lifecycle methods, in particular, enter().

http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2012/07/09/learning-d3-part-2

> But lets say to begin with, we just have a blank page, with no
>   paragraphs. How do we get new paragraphs on the page, representing the
>   data? Enter .enter(). When we call enter() on an existing selection,
>   we switch to a sub-selection representing the data that is yet to be
>   mapped to an element, because there is not yet enough of them on the
>   page to represent all of the current dataset. In other words, if there
>   are more datums in our dataset than elements on the page, the “enter”
>   sub-selection represents the yet-to-be-added elements.

From the man himself, Bostock has a easy to follow walk through on bar charts. This may help clear up any confusing in what your implementation is missing.

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

There's that pesky enter() again.

> Since we know the selection is empty, the returned update and exit
>   selections are also empty, and we need only handle the enter selection
>   which represents new data for which there was no existing element. We
>   instantiate these missing elements by appending to the enter
>   selection.
>
> var barEnter = barUpdate.enter().append("div");

Comment: That's not OP's problem: you can append a path without an enter selection.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm light on D3 and its just the first thing I happened to notice missing that I've seen used on every D3 project... so whats the bug?

There is missing code from the example as it seems however... a `tempArrMap` variable is used yet undefined in this snippet.

Comment: Parsing the dates. OP is passing numbers to a time scale.

Comment: Not sure how that is breaking their application... they parse into Time objects.
     var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain(d3.extent([new Date(1881,0,1),new Date(2015,0,1)]))
        .range([0, width]); // output
undefined
xScale
function r(n){return(o||(o=i(a,c,f?eu(t):t,s)))(+n)}
new Date(1881, 0, 1)
Sat Jan 01 1881 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST).... and that didn't paste so well..

Comment: A scale doesn't parse anything. You have to pass date objects to a time scale, not numbers.